# Two pattern aliases for a node type

Tags: panels, path-aliases

I am using [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) with a Node template to override the view of a content-type Employee.

At the moment I am using [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to give a clean url of /Employee/[Employee-Name].

I'd like to use the panels selection criteria to have an alternative view of that node template by using a path such as /Employee/[Employee-Name]/View2

How would I go about generating the second alias pattern?

Comment: I would go for two views showing only one node, each with the relevant path (i.e : `Employee/%` and Employee/%/View2). You can then override each path with the relevant template variation.